# Call custom colormap by name

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I've seen many posts about creating custom colormaps in `matplotlib`, however I couldn't find whether it is possible to call such custom colormap by name (which I guess requires first some way to add the custom colormap to the list of findable/built-in colormaps).

As an example, I'd like to do something like:
`plt.scatter(..., cmap='my_cmap')`

I know that I could just pass directly the colormap there, but what if I often wants to use this colormap and would like to avoid having to retrieve/define it before passing it as `cmap` argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [*Matplotlib 3.7*](https://matplotlib.org/3.7.1/index.html), you can/need to use [`register`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/cm_api.html#matplotlib.cm.ColormapRegistry.register) :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(["#fd635c", "#00b9a8", "#124191"])

mpl.colormaps.register(cmap, name="my_cmap")

np.random.seed(123456)
x = np.random.rand(100) * 3,
y = np.random.rand(100) * 3
c = np.random.randint(0, 3, 100)

plt.scatter(x=x, y=y, c=c, cmap="my_cmap")

plt.colorbar()
```

Output :

```
display(cmap)
```

[image]

```
plt.show();
```

[image]